# Statistical significance in yes/no poll question

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

I have no statistics background, but an trying to complete my first quantitative research survey writeup for my researcher in education class and hope someone can direct me.

I created a poll of 62 teachers and am trying to analyze the following 4 questions

1. Do they use social media personally (yes/no)
2. Do they use SM in the classroom (yes/no)
3. If they plan to use in future in classroom (yes/no)
4. What type of secondary school do you work in (public/private)

I am running into a challenge with how to complete a "test of statistical significance for this data"

The professor suggested using either a t-test or ANOVA and provided links, but the data I have do not seem to fit into the formulas.

Is anyone able to provide some guidance about how to test this type of survey? Is there a different way to analyze the data?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since this looks like a class assignment, please add the "self-study" tag. See [homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: Asking if some data “are significant” is not a well-defined problem. If you are doing a test at all (it's not the only way to analyze quantitative data), you would typically test a specific hypothesis, perhaps compare several subgroups or test if there is a particular relationship between several variables. You need to tell us what you are trying to find out in this study.

Comment: I am trying to find out which group of teachers uses social media in their classrooms - private versus public

Comment: what other tools are used to analyze quantitative data?

Comment: I think you can go for either hi square test or F-test.

Answer (score 2):

The professor's advice seems odd, if this is all the data you have; also "t-test of ANOVA" is not a sensible phrase. Is it a typo of "t-test or ANOVA"?  Even if it is a typo I think it strange advice. T-tests and ANOVAs are for comparing mean scores. In your question, there don't seem to be any means (or things to take the mean of).

Your title mentions "statistical significance" but that requires some hypothesis that you wish to test. What is your hypothesis?

What do you want to find out about the four questions that you asked? e.g.

What percent of teachers said "yes" to each?

(responding to your comment)

For public vs. private school you will have (for each of the four questions) a 2x2 table of results. Have you studied any statistical method that looks at that?

Similarly for personal vs. classroom use, you have a 2x2 table.

Unless you have yet more information....

How the four questions relate to each other?

Something else? (if so, what?)

Do you have any other information about the professors? If so, what do you have and how do you want to use it?

Comment: " Is it a typo of "t-test or ANOVA"?" yes - this was a typo - my apologies   - as you suspected it should read "t-test or ANOVA"

Comment: I am trying to find out if there is a difference in teachers who use social media in their classrooms when comparing public and private school settings; Also am interested to see the relationship between teachers who use social media personally and in their classroom ; In reviewing my notes for this class I believe the professor shared the T test and ANOVA as suggestions to use in determining statistical significance - I am hoping to find a tool which will help me evaluate the data I have collected with regard to accuracy and sample size

Comment: is the 2x2 table of results the same as a chi square?

Comment: I came across information about using fishers exact test when analyzing categorical(nominal) variables - this seems to fit my data, but as the tool is new to me wanted to gain some support for this idea

Comment: How many teachers are there in public and private schools? Are there an equal number in public and private (31 in each?) If there are an equal number in each group, then an ANOVA could fit nicely.

Comment: I would recommend starting with chi-square tests. They are very basic and perfect for 2x2 tables. Once you have examined your variables against each other, you can then gradually make it more complicated by looking at more than pairs of variables.